# How to write a test in Java that checks if an object is being used in JMock or JUnit?

Tags: java, testing, junit, jmock

I'm writing some tests for a Java program, and I need to test if my object is added into a List x amount of times.

Below is a hypothetical code snippet....

```
ObjectWithList objectWithList = new ObjectWithList();    

JMock context = new JMock();
ObjectInterface oInterfaceMock = (ObjectInterface)context.mock(ObjectInterface.class);

context.checking(new Expectations{{
    oneOf(oInterfaceMock).makeSureIamOnlyStoredSomewhereOnce();
}});

context.assertIsSatisfied(); // This will be successful if objectWithList calls add only 
//once.
```

I don't know if JUnit has  a better way of testing this, any help would be much appreciated. I've been trying to do google searches, and searching through previous questions on Stack but I've had no luck.

Thank you so much everyone, any help is always appreciated!!

Comment: You want to a call a method `X`, that fills `objectWithList` with an object `Y` n times? The method `X` does not appear in your code snippet, the object `Y` is probably `oInterfaceMock`, but it can be a simple object, there is no need to mock it. Did I understand your problem? Then add the call of method `X` to your snippet, and point out how `objectWithList` is filled in this method (is it an argument of `X` or a field of `X`s object).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this without JMock. you could simply write a function that counts how many times a list contains an object:

```
public int getCount(List<?> list, Object object) {
  int count = 0;
  for (Object element : list) {
    if (object.equals(element)) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

There are other possible implementations, but this one is obviously correct. Next, you can write an assertion:

```
public void assertAppearsNTimes(List<?> list, Object object, int n) {
  if (n == getCount(list, object)) {
    return;
  }
  fail("Object " + object + " does not appear in list "
      + n + " times: " + list);
}
```